# python unittest import classes sub directories

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, python-import, python-unittest

I have a project structured like this:

```
|tools/
|-- test/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_class1.py
|   |-- test_class2.py
|   
|-- tools/
|-- __init__.py
|   |-- class1.py
|   |-- class2.py
|   
|-- test_runner (Python script that calls unittest.TestLoader().discover('test'))
|-- README.md
```

I want to run `test_runner` and have it execute all the tests in the `test` folder. My individual tests would have a line like this: `from test_class import TestClass` to test the appropriate class.

`test_runner` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(__file__) + '/tools') 

suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('test')
results = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
if len(results.errors) > 0 or len(results.failures) > 0:
    sys.exit(1)
sys.exit()
```

Right now this isn't working, my test files aren't able to import their corresponding classes. I can get it to work if I do `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/file` but I want to get this working through a script.

I also tried `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/tools')` but that doesn't work because **file** returns nothing when I use `sys.path.insert`.

Comment: Any reason not to use `nosetests`?

Comment: It's not too big of a project so I didn't want to add too many dependencies. I thought there would be an easier way to do this that I was missing. Does it look like `nosetests` is the only option?

Comment: It's not the only option, but I wouldn't consider a test runner a dependency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make sure you use absolute imports, by specifying your package name ("tools" in your case).
You don't have to modify your system path at all.

For example, with this project structure and by running main.py:

```
project
    main.py
    package1
        __init__.py
        module1.py
    package2
        __init__.py
        module2.py
```

In module1.py, you should use

```
from package2 import module2
```

or

```
from package2.module2 import myclass
```

This is absolute import.
No need for system path modification

Comment: What would it be if I wanted to import main.py from module1.py?

Comment: For best practices, I wouldn't recommend to do that. In my example main.py is only the launching file. Just like "manage.py" in Django project structure for example (in case it helps to understand ...)
If you have some code in main.py, move it to another module that module1 can call.